# List spacing inside a table

Tags: tables, spacing, lists

Please take a look on the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{ \textwidth}| } 

\hline
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item in a list
\end{enumerate} \\

\hline
Item not in a list \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

The "Item in a list" has an extra spacing at top and bottom inside a table cell in comparison to "Item not in a list".

How to reduce this top and bottom spacing?

Comment: Related Question: [Enumerate environment with tabular layout](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29511/enumerate-environment-with-tabular-layout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using `enumitem`:

Taking a hint form Stephan Lehmke, with [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) you could use the inline `enumerate*` environment (assuming you have a single item):

[image]

The `enumitem` package also includes a `resume` option which would be useful if you wanted to resume the list in a different row.

#### References:

- [What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem)
- [Suggestions for transitioning from paralist to enumitem package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/suggestions-for-transitioning-from-paralist-to-enumitem-package)
- [Can't get my head around enumitem's spacing parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38850/cant-get-my-head-around-enumitems-spacing-parameters/)

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{ \textwidth}| }

\hline
\begin{enumerate*}
    \item Item in a list
\end{enumerate*} \\

\hline
Item not in a list \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

---

### Using a Counter:

Alternatively, you could just use your own counter which yields results identical to above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{MyCounter}%
\newcommand*{\MyItem}{\refstepcounter{MyCounter}\theMyCounter.~}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{ \textwidth}| }

\hline
    \MyItem Item in a list\\
\hline
Item not in a list \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried

```
\usepackage{paralist}
```

and then

```
\begin{inparaenum}
\item Item in a list\par
\item Item in a list
\end{inparaenum}\\
```

The explicit `\par` looks really weird, but with all other enumerate constructs provided by `paralist`, the extra spacing was still there.