# Why does the vertical alignment not match the expected behaviour at p columns in tabular env?

Tags: tables, lists, vertical-alignment

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
a & 
\begin{itemize}
 \item sd
\end{itemize}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I want to get a table with a on the left side and a list (only one entry at the moment) on the right.

What I get is that the list is positioned below the a (seems to be aline below).

Can you tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: What is your expected behavior when there are more than 1 item?

Comment: Also see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50571/list-spacing-inside-a-table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The space is there because inside the cell, a paragraph is first started, then it's ended and your `itemize` starts. You can wrap the code inside `minipage` to get the desired output:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & \begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
 \item sd
\end{itemize}\end{minipage}\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, I would prefer to make an environment of its own:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][5cm]{\minipage{#1}\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}\endminipage}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & \begin{tabitemize}[5cm]
 \item sd
\end{tabitemize}\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I made the width as an optional arugument (I suppose you'll fix one width value). As well, I use the direct call to `\minipage...\endminipage` to avoid one unnecessary grouping.

According to suggest by **azetina** and **A.Ellet** I propose another version:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][\hsize]%
  {\minipage[t]{#1}\begin{itemize}}%
  {\end{itemize}\endminipage}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe} % not needed

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{}X@{}}
Hello & \begin{tabitemize}
 \item \lipsum[1-2] % lipsum command just produces some dummy text
 \item \lipsum[3]
\end{tabitemize}\\ 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

- We use `tabularx` to use the whole width of a page.
- We set the argument to `minipage` to `\hsize` which seems to be the right approach according to `tabularx` manual
- We set `[t]` argument to `minipage` to get the right vertical alignment
- By `@{}` we remove the (probably unnecessary) horizontal spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

@tohecz solution works quite well.  But what if you want the first item of the `list` to align on the baseline of the content in the first column.  You could take **tehecz** solution and modify it slightly to get

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][5cm]{\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & \begin{tabitemize}[5cm]
 \item first item
 \item second item
\end{tabitemize}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I had to introduce a new grouping (unless *tohecz* knows about to do this more directly) to tell the minipage that I wanted the `baseline` set on the first line.  That's what the optional argument `[t]` to the `minipage` environment is doing.

Comment: It would be good if the width of the minipage uses the remaining textwidth space